# How can I reload a webpage using grunt-contrib-watch?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I have a project folder "Project1" with the following files:

```
/Project1/index.html
/Project1/bar.json
```

Is there a way to setup grunt-contrib-watch to reload index.html any time bar.json is modified?

Comment: You could specify the `livereload` option for your watch task (along with specifying `*.json` files to be watched), grab the LiveReload plugin for Chrome, and activate it. That'll do the trick.

Comment: In the past I've used the steps you listed in order to livereload css. But, this time, I'm looking to reload/refresh (not livereload) the entire webpage.

Comment: If a `json` file is edited and fed to the live reload server, it should refresh the entire page. Otherwise you can write a task that triggers the refresh and have the watch task run it when that file is edited.

Comment: Yes, that works. Would either of you like to post the answer? Or, let me know if I should post it.